# What is the purpose of MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS and SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS folders in SQL Server 17.9

Tags: sql, sql-server

Anybody knows why I have MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS and SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS folders in location `C:\Windows\Users` after installing SQL Server 17.9?

Is it a problem to delete both of them?

Comment: They're be part of the service accounts set up. Why do you *want* to delete them though? They can't be taking up a lot of storage space, probably an MB or 2 at most.

Comment: I am feel disturbed with the location, both of them in C:\Users folder. Is it normal and other people have both folder in C:\Users? I think it should be in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: "disturbed"? I don't think it really caused you any emotional or mental problems. As I said they are linked to Service accounts. Service Accounts are users; where else would you therefore expect user related information to be stored other than in the Users directory?

Comment: I just wanna make sure my folder in place. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by that. It won't have effected the files in your user directory, it made different directories; as you have stated.

Answer (score 1):

They are Service Accounts.  They are essentially fake users that get their own user profile directories, which is why they exist in the User directory.  **You should keep them there (intact) if you plan on continuing to use SQL Server.**

In my case, I was trying to migrate user profiles from an SSD to an SSHD data drive, leaving behind a Directory Junction/Symbolic Link.  I found it incredibly frustrating that even after uninstalling all SQL Server stuff, these guys remained behind.  That is a legitimate reason to get rid of them.  You don't have to have mental issues to not want uninstall residue left over.  And, I think it's okay to be concerned about potential conflicts down the road, and not wanting to assume that a reinstall will somehow catch it.

Here is how to remove them.  (Again, only if not using SQL Server at all):

> • Remove the services in a `cmd` window:
>
> ```cmd
> sc delete MSSQL$SQLExpress
> sc delete SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS
> ```

then

> • Open `services.msc` and Stop the services (I can't remember what they're called, but they both start with SQL and have SQLEXPRESS in their name)

then

> • Delete the directories.  If doing it from a `cmd` window:
>
> ```cmd
> rd "c:\users\MSSQL$SQLExpress\" /s/q
> rd "c:\users\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS\" /s/q
> ```